# Async tests fail due to timeout

Tags: jestjs, angular12

We are using jest 27 for our project in Angular 12 for running our unit tests. Locally, these tests run correctly but runnig them in a cloud agent pipe they break, appearing this error:

thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

This is the part of code that breaks:

```
const createHost = createHostFactory({
component: Component,    
imports: [
  TranslateModule.forRoot(),
  GridModule,
  MaterialWrapperTestingModule,
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  TooltipModule,
  TableEditionToolbarModule,
],
providers: [
  { provide: ContactsService, useValue: contactsServiceSpy },
  { provide: CustomerService, useValue: customerServiceSpy },
  { provide: CustomerDetailFacade, useValue: customerFacadeSpy },
  { provide: HeaderMenuFacade, useValue: headerMenuFacadeSpy },
  { provide: ContextFacade, useValue: contextFacadeSpy },
  { provide: MatDialog, useValue: dialogMock },
],});

 beforeEach(() => {
  host = createHost('<component-selector></component-selector>', { detectChanges: true, 
  props: { structure } });
  return host.fixture.whenStable();
 });
```

It takes too much time to run the tests and the task fails.

We have done several changes in order to solve it, but nothing helps:

- We have use already jest.setTimeout(newTimeout)
- We have alse used --runInBand to run tests serially

Comment: Thanks Steven, I have editted my question adding more code. I have already increased the time out and I have also ensured doing the return but the problem persist.

Comment: There is still so much missing to help with.  While I am no expert, I am not sure even how to begin to help with the little amount of information you provided.  Try breaking this down to a very simple example.  For instance, simply try testing the ContactsService, and see if you have an error.  I would try to get the very basic tests working on its own, and then the larger ones. I see that you have this working locally, but not in the cloud. Maybe try using the --detectOpenHandles Jest option?